# Cypress - canvas element drag n drop

Tags: javascript, canvas, automation, cypress, android-canvas

I need to drag n drop over on a canvas element, I tried some code examples but unfortunately, they didn't help my need.

(import '@4tw/cypress-drag-drop') I added drag n drop plugin too and with using that plugin did not solve the problem.

Is anyone know how to do that?

```
Then('using pan tool `already selected` locate the tool where the incident happened', () => {
    cy.get('canvas[style="width: 600px; height: 558px; display: block;"]').trigger('mousedown', 'top', { force: true })
    cy.wait(3000).get('canvas[style="width: 600px; height: 558px; display: block;"]').trigger('mousemove', 'bottom', { force: true })
})
```

I need to mouse move, click, and mouse move somewhere else instead of center direction.

[image]

if the operation success as you can see here the picture is moving directionally

[image]

as you can see that element is a canvas element.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this. It will works.**

```
cy.get('canvas[style="width: 600px; height: 558px; display: block;"]').trigger("mousemove")
      .trigger("mousedown", { which: 1 })
      .trigger("mousemove", {
        clientX: 300,
        clientY: 30,
        screenX: 300,
        screenY: 30,
        pageX: 800,
        pageY: 130,
      })
      .trigger("mouseup", { force: true });
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work :(

Comment: use {force:true}for mosemove, mousedown, mousemove and mouseup. cy.get('canvasSelector').trigger("mousemove",{force:true}).trigger("mousedown",, {
        clientX: 300,
        clientY: 30,
        screenX: 300,
        screenY: 30,
        pageX: 800,
        pageY: 130,force:true
      }).trigger("mouseup",{force:true}) have to edit the x and y values in mousemove

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get('canvas[style="width: 600px; height: 558px; display: block;"]').trigger("mousemove",{force:true)
      .trigger("mousedown", { which: 1,force:true })
      .trigger("mousemove", {
        clientX: 300,
        clientY: 30,
        screenX: 300,
        screenY: 30,
        pageX: 800,
        pageY: 130,
force:true
      })
      .trigger("mouseup", { force: true });
```